# variable transformation

Tags: regression, predictive-models, data-transformation, r-squared

friends,
I want to use regression for prediction purposes with a sample of over 20k.

I have the following results for the OLS with adj R-squared of 0.64:

[image]

[image]

my first question is: can I say that the normality of the residuals is not significantly violated?

Also, when I used a transformation such as SQUARE for the dependent variable, the Adjusted R-squared improved to 0.71 but residual by predicted plot got a bell-shaped pattern. my question is that can i use that transformation just because it improved my adjusted R-squared? Is that a sign of some thing specific?

Thanks

Comment: If you're only using the regression for predictive purposes, you probably don't *care* if the normality of residuals is violated.

Comment: You need to address more basic considerations first.  How many distinct values of "service time" are there?  Why should the OLS model be appropriate for them?  These residuals are decidedly non-normal, particularly insofar as they typically have definite upper and lower bounds.  That's a hint that you ought to be using a different model altogether.

Comment: @MatthewDrury. thanks for your response. Yes, I want just to predict the service time. so interesting! I do not need to check the model assumptions?! just pay attention to the adj-R-square? do you have any suggestion as a reference to see what should I do and what is not necessary if I want just to predict the values of the dependent variable?

Comment: @whuber, thanks for your response. service time is a continuous variable that it gets values from 5 to 75 (integer). I have 26 variables which include 25 categorical and one continuous variable. I need to predict service time and just need the predicted value of service time. I have no clue where to start from. I thought I  need to start from OLS with all main effects and then with interaction (stepwise) and also decision tree. I thought I need to check the model assumptions whenever I use a model. Can you help me what should be my steps? I really appreciate your guidance.

Comment: @Maryam Many of those model assumptions are there to support inferential uses of the model.  In particular, the normality assumption is there to ensure that the distribution of parameter estimates is known, which is used in the calculation of confidence intervals and p-values.  For predictive applications, it is much more important to make sure that the model fit is good by including non-linearities like splines, and using cross validation to measure the generalization properties of the model.